# Passing children to a component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `NavigationBar` class that is supposed to behave like a pretty common navbar. I want the buttons on the left and the right (and the title) to be customizable. But the standard way (pass as `this.props.children`) doesnt't reflect the semantics (that the first child is used not like the second one and the fact that there are exactly 3 children, which is also subject for change in specializations like hamburger menu navbar/navbar with a back button) and won't look good. And the ugly way to use props to pass components is not any good as well, because I cannot pass any props to them. Am I missing some other way?

Comment: Can you provide code examples? It's not clear what you are asking and what you have tried.

Comment: "And the ugly way to use props to pass components is not any good as well, because I cannot pass any props to them." Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass JSX to the props of your NavBar, similar to how Material-UI does it. [See here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar). That way you are able to pass props to these components.